# Delete directory using Laravel Storage Facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to delete a directory using Laravel Storage Facade, here's what I tried

```
Storage::delete('xtestx');
```

But unfortunately, it does not work, instead it gives me this error.

> storage\app\resources\xtestx): Permission denied

any ideas, help, clues, recommendations, suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The method `delete()` is for deleting a file, to delete a directory you can use `Storage::deleteDirectory('xtestx');`.

Comment: When using disks, this is the implementation: `Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory('xtestx');`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Rifki answer.

The delete method accepts a single filename or an array of files to remove from the disk:

You need to use the Storage facade in order to use the `deleteDirectory()` method.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::deleteDirectory('xtestx');
```

Refer to the Documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#directories